# curl request via Nginx with mTLS enabled

Tags: nginx, ssl, curl

When Nginx is configured to verify server's TLS chain like this:

```
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate some.pem;
  proxy_ssl_verify on;
  proxy_ssl_verify_depth 3;
```

and testing using a curl command, will both curl and Nginx perform server TLS chain verification?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming curl makes requests through the nginx proxy (using `-x/--proxy` if HTTP inside TLS; `--proxytunnel` for other protocols) then yes, both curl and nginx are verifying the server certificate by constructing a chain from that certificate to a trusted root certificate. If you don't want curl to verify the certificate chain, you can use `-k/--insecure`.

EDIT: If your concern has to do with mutual TLS (i.e. curl is sending a client certificate to the server) then please edit your question to make clear your concern about mTLS. I did not consider mTLS to be relevant to the question because you asked

> will both curl and Nginx perform *server* TLS chain verification?

(emphasis mine)

mTLS certificate validation/verification would involve the client's TLS chain.